# API LIKES facebook

Tags: facebook, api

Since trying to get help from FB is pointless I thought I would give this a shot.

I have a business page. I have run several ads and targeted foreign countries/languages. Page was opened 11/15 and by April 14 2016 I had roughly 1000-1200 followers-likes.

On April 15 my page likes shot up and kept doing so for approx 2.5 weeks. In that 2.5 week time frame I gained about 5000 followers which I now believe to be fake. They don't engage with anything and it is really killing my page. When I check my page analytical details it shows that those 5000 page likes are API Likes.

What does this mean? I am assuming that some like farmer has latched onto my account due to where I was boosting posts to and is now liking my page through all his fake profiles so he can keep them looking real.

My question is if I delete all the fakes will I be OK to continue using the account or should I close it and start over?

Comment: Facebook pages can not be liked via API, so that it shows them as “API likes” in analytics doesn’t make much sense.